# Steps to take to deploy AjaxControlToolKit.dll to test and production servers

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have added AjaxControlToolKit.dll to my web project and using couple of controls on my web form. What steps to I need to take to deploy to test and production servers? It works fine on my development. AjaxControlToolKit.dll is in my bin folder.

Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just deploy it to your server with your application and keep it in the /bin folder.

If you're using .NET 2.0 however then you needed to install the ASP.NET AJAX Extensions in order to get it working. If you deploy such an application to your server you also need to install those extensions there in order to have your toolkit working.
If you're using .NET 3.5 (sp1) then all the Ajax goodness is already baked in and you don't have to install extra extensions.

Comment: @nav100: if you like it and it worked, please mark it as the answer. This'll help you help out others.

Comment: I have the similar issue, I have included System.Web.Extensions.dll in my project. It working perfectly on local system but the ajax controls does not work on server. I have added a separate question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729997/ajax-controls-not-working-on-server). Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

AjaxControlToolkit.dll just needs to exist with your test/production binaries--make sure you compile against the same versions for future updates.

If everything works in dev, your page directives (`@Register...`) along with the library should be sufficient.